# Capture percentage download from curl in real time

Tags: macos, bash, shell, curl, sed

I am downloading a file from remote server through `curl`. The script will be packaged as an app through [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus), which lets the app show percentage progress if the script output is of the format `PROGRESS:\d+\n`, as described [here](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/files/manpages/PlatypusDocumentation.html#10-3). I tried doing this

```
curl -O <remote_file> | sed -r 's/[# ]//g;s/^/#/g'
```

to get the output percentage, it didn't work. I tried out another method as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139997). That didn't work as well.

How do I capture the percentage download and echo text like `PROGRESS:<percentage>\n` in parallel.

P.S Perhaps because it is Bash and GNU Sed is not there, it is not working as expected.

Comment: There is nothing GNU sed specific about the script you posted, you're using standard sed BREs to just get rid of the `-r`. You might have more luck if you post a few lines of sample input and expected output rather than expecting people to go clicking around the web for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `curl` outputs information like progression on the standard error output, so you have to consider STDERR at least, for example by merging it with STDOUT using `2>&1`.

Second, `curl` is not producing `\n` symbols while downloading the file but stays on the same line to overwrite displayed progression as the file is downloaded. You may thus have to read char by char the output stream, for example by using `IFS= read -r -n1 char`.

Given a `curl`-like progression char stream, I suggest to use a guard mechanism to know which char has to be kept:

- If it is a number, we now want to keep the characters.
- If it is a `%` symbol, we now don't want to keep the characters anymore

The following code uses these ideas and may suit your problem.

```
curl -# -O URL 2>&1 | while IFS= read -r -n1 char; do
    [[ $char =~ [0-9] ]] && keep=1 ;
    [[ $char == % ]] && echo "PROGRESS:$progress" && progress="" && keep=0 ;
    [[ $keep == 1 ]] && progress="$progress$char" ;
done
```

Enjoy !

PS : You can of course use it as a oneliner by concatening all this code but I thought it'd be easier to read like that.

Comment: That was neat! Thanks!

Comment: By any chance, is it possible to strip off the decimal and get only the integer part?

Comment: Sure, just use `echo "PROGRESS:${progress%,*}"` (`%,*` means "suppress the shortest string on the right side that matches `,*`")

Comment: Umm, no, I am still getting 0.0, 0.1, etc....This is what I am running:

`curl -# -O http://java6damn.s3.amazonaws.com/javaforosx.dmg 2>&1 | while IFS= read -r -n1 char; do
    [[ $char =~ [0-9] ]] && keep=1 ;
    [[ $char == % ]] && echo "PROGRESS:${progress%,*}" && progress="" && keep=0 ;
    [[ $keep == 1 ]] && progress="$progress$char" ;`

Comment: Oh my bad, my LANG is on french ... use rather `echo "PROGRESS:${progress%.*}"`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!